# Setting attribute to NULL in Yii2 and save to database

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

In Yii we had `CDbExpression('NULL')` what is the equivalent in Yii2? Need to set a database column back to `null` via a model in Yii2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If i remember correctly yii2 don't make a string conversion for null value  when you can try setting the value to NULL

```
$model->field = NULL;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set NULL value directly to model attribute:

```
$model->field=null;
```

or config default value in rules() method

```
[['field'],'default',null]
```

Comment: The correct syntax for the rules method is:
[['field'], 'default', 'value' => null],